# OPC.Tests.SmokeTest (TestFixtureSetUp): SetUp : OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

I am trying to use CssSelector to locate an element on my webpage. I am using Firefox driver.

Here is how I am using the locator (I checked that Selenium IDE is able to locate my element with this

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "label:contains('Version: 2.0.')")]
public IWebElement labelVersion;
```

But when use this in the C# code and initialize it with 
PageFactory.InitElements in my constructor.

I hit this error... (the error itself is pretty clear but I don't know how to fix it)

Appreciate any inputs.

> OPC.Tests.SmokeTest (TestFixtureSetUp): SetUp :
>   OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException : The given selector
>   css=label:contains('Version: 2.0.') is either invalid or does not
>   result in a WebElement. The following error occurred: [Exception...
>   "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12" nsresult:
>   "0x8053000c (NS_ERROR_DOM_SYNTAX_ERR)"  location:
>   "file:///........../anonymous439571104.webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js
>   Line: 5811"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selenium delegates CSS queries down to the browser. This means that CSS queries need to follow CSS standard.

Unfortunately :contains was removed from the standard a while back. I recommend that you redo your selector with whats available from the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) or use XPATH.

:contains works in Selenium RC because RC uses Sizzle, the selector search library in jQuery if you are wondering why it works in RC and not WebDriver

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. I am already resorting to XPath for this as I did not have time to debug the issue, figured someone here knows the answer and I was rit!